# Automating the install of GFortran and Python3

Tags: python, linux, bash, installation, homebrew

I'd like to write a bash script that will be executed on new users' linux machines. The script should make sure the machine is ready to compile and run several fortran and python scripts. My intent was to check for GCC and subsequently check for gfortran in GCC and then use homebrew to install the gfortran formula if not present. Similarly with python, I would use pip to install python3 if python isn't up to date.

I would like some advice before I begin. What are some best practices for checking for programs and installing them through a behind the scenes bash script? What are things to be careful for? I realize this question is vague but literally any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are homebrew, pip and gcc preinstalled in all linux distributions? Mine doesn't have homebrew, and I installed pip (the package) manually a few months ago

Comment: @CooperMaira : I would first check, whether the executables are already in the PATH (since the user might already have installed them somewhere) and verify the version, i.e. checking `python3 --version`. If something is missing, I would look at the intended installation location, whether the executable is there. If it is, I would abort with a message that the user needs to update his PATH settings. If it still is missing, I would check whether `brew` is available. If it is not, I would abort with a message saying that homebrew needs to be installed. Otherwise I would run `brew`.

Comment: @oguzismail homebrew is generally not installed on linux machines but it's obviously a great package manager because it stresses compatibility and flexibility over version specification. GCC is generally installed on linux machines but for some reason usually doesn't contain gfortran even though gfortan is installed into the gcc once installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible different approach to consider.

If the packages that you want are available for installation via the standard package manager for the Linux distribution that you are using, you could build a metapackage which, when installed, will force the installation of all of the components.  (A metapackage is one which does not directly contain any software itself but which lists a number of dependencies that the package manager will need to satisfy when installing it.)

If you also set up a repository on an http server containing your metapackage, and configure the package manager on the clients to point to it, then if you later decide to update the list of packages contained in your standard software suite across all the client machines, all you need to do is to publish a new version of your metapackage to the repository, and have the client machines rerun their operating system's software updater.  For the individual software components listed in the metapackage, the software update will pick up any updates to these in the ordinary way, provided that the dependency information in the metapackage does not specify an exact version (you could make the metapackage depend on `>=` some version number).

This is from experience where this approach has worked well in setting up and maintaining a common software platform across a large number of machines (including nodes of a compute cluster) -- although in cases where the required software components are *not* available in standard package repositories, it is then necessary to build a package for it locally and publish that to your repository; this can then be added as a requirement in your metapackage.

The above is in general terms, but taking the specific example on which this experience is based, if the client machines are running CentOS, then you would create a meta-RPM with dependencies on packages in standard repositories (e.g. base and EPEL) plus any other RPMs that you need to build locally, publish it to the repository on the http server and use `createrepo` to construct the necessary repository metadata, and create a config file in `/etc/yum.repo.d` on the clients to point to your repository and run `yum install <your_meta_package>`.  Any subsequent `yum update` on the clients will pick up any changes that you push to your repository.  The http server itself is simply serving static content, so does not need special configuration.

For Ubuntu etc, you could do similarly but with deb packages and APT.

One thing worth mentioning is that the above is aimed at a rather homogeneous environment, where the same operating system is in use on all the client machines.  If you want to cater for a more heterogeneous environment, then an alternative approach would be to use conda.  You could similarly maintain a conda channel containing a metapackage.

Comment: Thank you, I love this idea. I had been flirting with a similar idea at a lower level. Because one of the scripts is in python and requires several python packages that users need to install before running, I was going to make that python script its own locally shared package that contained those dependancies in it's setup file so they would be automatically managed. I like the idea of bringing this concept to a more overarching level.

Comment: Are meta packages managed through linux naturally or does linux require a package manager like homebrew to install metapackages?

Comment: @CooperMaira I can't advise on homebrew because I haven't used it, though it seems that it can be used to manage packages that are installed in home directories. I was referring really to the OS's own package manager such as yum or APT that are typically used for installation into system paths. When you use these to install a package, they will also automatically install any additional packages to satisfy dependencies. So if you build your own package which provides no files of its own but lists a number of dependencies, installing it will force the installation of the dependencies...

Comment: @CooperMaira So for example, when create an RPM metapackage (which would typically be installed using yum) you could write a spec file in which the `%prep`, `%build` and `%install` recipes are empty, and so also is the `%files` list, but you have one or more `Requires:` headers.

Comment: That's what i was imagining as well. I would also like to take this opportunity to again express my appreciation for your help.

Comment: I guess i'm a little confused on package managers. Based on my research it sounds like brew is the yum equivalent for mac OSX. I guess I should have been more forthcoming about the fact that I'm actually working on a mac and the terminal is bash. I guess I considered this to be linux equivalent.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80711/how-to-install-apt-get-or-yum-on-mac-os-x#:~:text=5%20Answers&text=If%20you%20want%20the%20equivalent,X%2C%20you%20have%20two%20choices.&text=You%20can%20use%20brew%20install,to%20install%20the%20package%20available.&text=You%20need%20to%20install%20either%20Homebrew%20or%20YUM. as a reference to my last comment.